# Command Line tool is failing for inmemory

Tags: playorm

PlayOrm.java is working fine with below arguments:

-k playormks -s localhost:9160 -t cassandra

but when I gave only

-t inmemory

it is giving following exceptions:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.bindings.BootstrapImpl.createBestCassandraConfig(BootstrapImpl.java:73)
    at com.alvazan.orm.api.base.Bootstrap.createAndAddBestCassandraConfiguration(Bootstrap.java:77)
    at com.alvazan.ssql.cmdline.PlayOrm.main(PlayOrm.java:73)

Do I need to give something else as well with -t inmemory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, this is a bug(we will fix it).  Work around is to supply the seeds and keyspace even though you don't need them ;).

thanks,
Dean